# How to convert epoch time in to local time?

Tags: angular, datetime, angular6, epoch

I have converted date and time into epoch time. and again I have to convert this epoch time into date and time and display it on my html page.

```
    date: 4/5/2019
    time: 11:00
    calculated epochTime = 1554465600
```

I am able to get the date correctly as "**4/5/2019**" from the epoch time by using:

```
  {{epochTime *1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

but I am not able to get the time correctly.
I am trying like

```
  {{epochTime | date:'HH:mm'}}  // i am getting time as 5:16 AM but teh time should be 11:00
```

My time is wrong. Can anybody please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add timezone in pipe,

(By default it takes the local timezone of user machine)

and you can specify it in minutes for example for GMT-2, timezone: '-120'

```
{{ epochTime | date:'HH:mm' : '-120'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Baruch. Th expected output is 12:00. but I am getting 22:26.

Comment: What I wrote is just an example, of course you have to enter the time zone you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the problem is in the time zone. You can find the names of the files of the time zone [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/common/locales).

**app.module.ts**:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import locale from '@angular/common/locales/<NAME OF THE TIME ZONE FILE>';
registerLocaleData(locale, <NAME TIME ZONE>);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: <NAME TIME ZONE> }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```